# Marketing Cloud adding New User and New Account via API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap-api, account, user

Hi i am trying to create a new Account via API. I found the sample code from the below link. But I don't where to get the account ID or Client ID as i am creating new account.When i tried sending dummy client id getting this error
RequestID: d4fc3ea2-1c49-4a03-abee- Message: MemberID xxxxxx does not have access to ClientID[12345] PartnerClientKey[] UserID[] PartnerUserKey[] CustomerKey[] supplied in the Client object.

If anyone can share a sample .net code  of creating and deactivating Account via API any help will be greatly appreciated Thanks in advance.

http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/adding_a_new_user_to_an_existing_account/

Answer (score 2):

1) You should check your user permissions as described [here](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/enterprise/enterprise_overview/adding_and_managing_users_administrator_account/).

2) You can also double check this by replacing the parameters with actual values for an existing record (instead of creating dummy)

```
ClientID
PartnerClientKey
UserID
PartnerUserKey
CustomerKey
```

Set these in the code below and it should work if you've the appropriate permissions fixed.

```
public void testAddUserToAccount()
{
    Account account = new Account();
    Account.ID=12334;
    if (account != null)
    {
        AccountUser accountUser = new AccountUser();
        accountUser.Name = "ACRUZ";
        accountUser.UserID = "ACRUZ";
        accountUser.IsAPIUser = true;
        accountUser.IsAPIUserSpecified = true;
        accountUser.IsLocked = false;
        accountUser.IsLockedSpecified = true;
        accountUser.Password = "XXX";
        accountUser.MustChangePassword = false;
        accountUser.MustChangePasswordSpecified = true;
        accountUser.Email = "acruz@example.com";
        UserAccess access = new UserAccess();
        //3 CLIENT_ADMIN Add Users to Account 
        //4 PRO_ADMIN Create/View Accounts 
        access.ID = 3;
        access.IDSpecified = true; //.Net specific
        accountUser.UserPermissions = new UserAccess[] {access};
        //This tells that create user in subaccount
        ClientID clientID = new ClientID();
        clientID.PartnerClientKey = "12345";
        clientID.IDSpecified = true;
        accountUser.Client = clientID;
        APIObject[] apiObjects = {accountUser};
        String requestId = null;
        String overAllStatus = null;
        CreateResult[] results = partnerAPIWse.Create(new CreateOptions(), apiObjects, out requestId, out overAllStatus);
        if (results != null)
        {
            foreach (CreateResult result in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Status Message ### " +
                result.StatusMessage);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("Error ...... ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you let me know where can i find those values of partner keys(is this a external key or something different?).Appreciate your help